# vscode renders a color as a pallete

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, color-thief

the code I am rendering in vscode jupyter notebook is supposed to be green (47, 58, 39)
But it shows as a pallet of three colors. Why? please see screenshot

below is the code

```
from colorthief import ColorThief
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path("Z:\github\pop_crawler\pop_crawler\pop_crawler\1.png")
color_thief = ColorThief(str(path))
dominant_color = color_thief.get_color(quality=10)
palette = color_thief.get_palette(color_count=3)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(dominant_color)
plt.imshow([dominant_color])
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what happens outside VSC